How to proceed authentification and authorization between three layers?
I have a bunch of services divided into three parts:
First: custom authorization server as C# Web API. It handles users' info and returns tokens following authorization code flow.
Second: React with TypeScript frontend, which contains authorization server's admin panel and also a page with authentication form.
Third: other applications, mainly MVC (ASP.NET Core), so they have both backend and frontend parts.
The goal is to connect all this three parts. For example, I will name them according to the order given above. Let's assume that there is only one "third" application.
When I go to the page https://third.com/verysecretpage, the authorization filter checks for the presence of a token in the session and redirects to https://second.com/auth if nothing found:
public void OnAuthorization(AuthorizationFilterContext context)
{
    if (IsAnonymousAction(context)) return;

    string? accessToken = context.HttpContext.Session.GetString("accessToken");

    if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(accessToken))
        context.Result = new RedirectResult($"https://second:3000/auth?clientId=b4db6042-ae11-47ca-a1e7-c737fb0ee7f1&state=987654321");
}

private static bool IsAnonymousAction(AuthorizationFilterContext filterContext)
{
    return filterContext.ActionDescriptor.EndpointMetadata.Any(em => em.GetType() == typeof(AllowAnonymousAttribute));
}


On the page https://second:3000/auth?clientId=b4db6042-ae11-47ca-a1e7-c737fb0ee7f1&state=987654321 I enter username and password, making then a request to https://first.com/auth-code:
async function handleSubmit(event: React.FormEvent<HTMLFormElement>): Promise<void> {
    event.preventDefault();
    const formData = new FormData(event.currentTarget);
    const username = formData.get("username")!.toString();
    const password = formData.get("password")!.toString();
    
    const fetchURL = "https://first.com/auth-code";
    const data = {
        "responseType": "code",
        // Here i pass clientId and state from query parameters
        "clientId": clientId,
        "state": state
    };
    await fetch(fetchURL, {
        method: 'POST',
        body: JSON.stringify(data),
        headers: {
            'Content-Type': 'application/json',
            'Authorization': 'Basic ' + btoa(`${username}:${password}`),
        },
        redirect: "follow"
    }).then(
        response => { window.location.href = "https://third.com/verysecretpage" });
}

On this step everything goes wrong. The authorization server first responses with 302 redirect to https://third.com/receive-tokens, then successfully gives tokens to third. This endpoint looks like this:
[Route("/receive-tokens")]
[AllowAnonymous]
[EnableCors("Interface")]
public async Task<IActionResult> ReceiveTokens(string code, string? status = null)
{
    var client = new HttpClient();
    var request = new HttpRequestMessage(HttpMethod.Post, "https://first.com/token");
    var content = new StringContent("{" + $"\n  \"grantType\": \"authorization_code\",\n  \"code\": \"{code}\",\n  \"clientId\": \"b4db6042-ae11-47ca-a1e7-c737fb0ee7f1\"\n" + "}", null, "application/json");
    request.Content = content;
    var response = await client.SendAsync(request);
    response.EnsureSuccessStatusCode();
    // Authorization server sends RefreshToken in httpOnly cookies,here I get it
    var refreshToken = CookieGetter.GetRefreshTokenCookie(response);
    string responseContents = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
    var accessTokenResponse = JsonSerializer.Deserialize<AccessTokenResponse>(responseContents, jsonSerializerOptions)!;
    var tokensResponse = new TokensResponse { AccessTokenResponse = accessTokenResponse, RefreshToken = refreshToken };

    auth.SaveTokenValues(tokensResponse);

    return Ok();
}

// this is from Auth class in Models
public void SaveTokenValues(TokensResponse tokensResponse)
{
    _contextAccessor.HttpContext!.Session.SetString("accessToken", tokensResponse.AccessTokenResponse.AccessToken);
    _contextAccessor.HttpContext.Session.SetString("expiresAt", tokensResponse.AccessTokenResponse.ExpiresAt.ToString());
    _contextAccessor.HttpContext.Session.SetString("refreshToken", tokensResponse.RefreshToken);
}

// Some classes, stated above
public class TokensResponse
{
    public required AccessTokenResponse AccessTokenResponse { get; set; }
    public required string RefreshToken { get; set; }

}

public class AccessTokenResponse
{
    public required string TokenType { get; set; }

    public required string AccessToken { get; set; }

    public required DateTime ExpiresAt { get; set; }
}

How Session is configured:
builder.Services.AddSession(options =>
{
    options.IdleTimeout = TimeSpan.FromMinutes(10);
    options.Cookie.HttpOnly = true;
    options.Cookie.IsEssential = true;
});

Then second receives 200 OK response from third and redirects to https://third.com/verysecretpage. However, no tokens are present in HttpContext.Session and the loop starts again.
I can't figure out which way to go next. As far as I believe, the session ASP.NET Core exists only within the framework of an open web page, and when we switch to React, we no longer return to it. Should I try to implement authorization not through a filter, but using the built-in ASP.NET Core authorization mechanism? Or is there some way to save the user's session when navigating through the pages? Or is it possible to make the React not wait for a response, but immediately redirect (thus going to the page ASP.NET Core, saving tokens to the session)? Or I can't take out a page with a login and password in a separate client, and I have to do it on the side ASP.NET Core?

Finally I replaced redirect with 200 status code response, returning redirectUrl in body. Then used manual redirect: window.location.href = receivedRedirectUrl.
